# Result code = -32, RespMsg = The certificate chain did not validate, common name did not match URL

Tags: api, paypal, certificate, tls1.2

I run a small ecommerce website in the UK. I use PayPal pro uk (name may have changed) to accept card payments directly on my website.

I recently moved servers to comply with tls1.2 demands.

When somebody tried to pay by card on my site they get the following error:

```
Result code = -32, 
RespMsg = The certificate chain did not validate, common name did not match URL.  
Input Server Uri = https://payflowpro.paypal.com/
```

I've contacted PayPal without any response. Does anybody know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Reason at here is TLS1.2 conflict .NET version

Please refer below link to update .NET version

https://github.com/paypal/payflow-gateway/tree/master/dotNET

after you download file then execute some step below :

step 1 : copy dll to ->c:\windows\syswow64\Payflow_dotNET.dll

step 2 : register dll : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe c:\windows\syswow64\Payflow_dotNET.dll

Step 3 : check gacutil: gacutil /if c:\windows\syswow64\Payflow_dotNET.dll

after do it, everything work fine !

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue too, even TLS 1.2 had been enabled too.
Update below settings into system, my problem solved.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001